# Umbraco v4 vs Cute AJAX Uploader Control

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, umbraco

I have a custom user control that i use in a page in Umbraco CMS... since upgrading to version 4, it seems this user control wont work any longer.

The user control contains an ajax uploader control (support request post here: http://cutesoft.net/forums/53732/ShowThread.aspx#53732), which allows users to upload images, then displays the uploaded images to the user. The control and image displays are contained within an UpdatePanel, which is where this problem is - seems the data getting sent back to the updatePanel is not valid, so the client is spitting the dummy and throwing this error:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.

Details: Error parsing near '

<!DOCTYPE html PUBL'.
```

I think its somethihng to do with how Master Pages is implemented in Umbraco v4 that is causing this.  Any ideas as to why this may have happened, and what i can look at to try to solve it?

FYI, here's a blog post that describes the error and its possible causes:
http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx

i'm doing any Response.write or Response.Redirect in the updatePanel
I'm not using any response filters
I've disabled server trace
I'm not using response.transfer

But, regardless of the above, this works fine using the same usercontrol on an Umbraco v3 site, which leads me to believe its somethign to do with v4 that's caused this.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I know that this whole answer is not directly a fix for your problem, but more like a workaround. this is because I am not familiar with the custom control you use.
i will however take a look tonight at your problem and see if i can find a solution for the code and plugin you use currently.

in the mean time i might give you some idea of the ajax upload i am using myself.
i know its a big chunk of code, but if you are interested you can go for it :)

---

#### my example case

I have an upload control in my own website and it works perfectly with umbraco.
the form and upload are powered with jQuery (upload is handled by jQuery.AjaxUpload plugin)

and i created a generic handler inside my umbraco folder which handles the file on the server.
creating a media item in the media library for it (and in my case beeing an avatar uploader on your profile page, it also adds the newly created mediaitem to the member's avatar property)

jQuery code: (stored in script block in the head of your page, or in a separate script)

```
initializeChangeAvatarForm = function() {
    var button = $('#submitChangeAvatar'), interval;
    new AjaxUpload(button,{
        action: '/umbraco/AjaxFileUpload.ashx',
        name: 'myfile',
        onSubmit : function(file, ext){
            // change button text to uploading + add class (with animating background loading image)
            button.text('Uploading').addClass('loading');
            // If you want to allow uploading only 1 file at time,
            // you can disable upload button
            this.disable();
        },
        onComplete: function(file, response){
            button.text('Upload nieuw').removeClass('loading');
            // Although plugins emulates hover effect automatically,
            // it doens't work when button is disabled
            button.removeClass('hover');
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            // enable upload button
            this.enable();
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    initializeChangeMailForm();
});
```

html code in your body:

```
<div id="container"><h2>Upload Avatar</h2><button class="button" id="submitChangeAvatar" type="button">Upload new</button></div>
```

jQuery ajaxupload plugin: (/scripts/jQuery.ajaxupload.js)
'[since this code is too long i added a link directly to the .js file i use](http://www.komtuveu.be/scripts/jquery.ajaxupload.js)
'[and another link to the page where i got the plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)

handler .ashx: (stored inside /umbraco/AjaxFileUpload.ashx)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using umbraco.BusinessLogic;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member;

namespace SH.umbServices
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for $codebehindclassname$
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    public class AjaxFileUpload : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) 
        {
            string strResponse = "error";
            try 
            {
                //string strFileName = Path.GetFileName(context.Request.Files[0].FileName);
                //string strExtension = Path.GetExtension(context.Request.Files[0].FileName).ToLower();
                //string strSaveLocation = context.Server.MapPath("../images/temp") + "\\" + strFileName;
                //context.Request.Files[0].SaveAs(strSaveLocation);
                UmbracoSave(context);
                strResponse = "success";
            }
            catch
            { 
            }
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write(strResponse);
        }

        public bool IsReusable 
        {
            get 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        #region "umbMediaItem"
        protected string UmbracoSave(HttpContext context)
        {
            string mediaPath = "";

            if (context.Request.Files[0] != null)
            {
                if (context.Request.Files[0].FileName != "")
                {
                    // Find filename
                    string _text = context.Request.Files[0].FileName;
                    string _ext = Path.GetExtension(context.Request.Files[0].FileName);
                    string filename;
                    string _fullFilePath;

                    //filename = _text.Substring(_text.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1, _text.Length - _text.LastIndexOf("\\") - 1).ToLower();
                    filename = Path.GetFileName(_text);
                    string _filenameWithoutExtention = filename.Replace(_ext, "");
                    int _p = 1212; // parent node.. -1 for media root)

                    // create the Media Node
                    umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media.Media m = umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media.Media.MakeNew(
                        _filenameWithoutExtention, umbraco.cms.businesslogic.media.MediaType.GetByAlias("image"), User.GetUser(0), _p);

                    // Create a new folder in the /media folder with the name /media/propertyid
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(umbraco.GlobalSettings.Path + "/../media/" + m.Id.ToString()));
                    _fullFilePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(umbraco.GlobalSettings.Path + "/../media/" + m.Id.ToString() + "/" + filename);
                    context.Request.Files[0].SaveAs(_fullFilePath);

                    // Save extension
                    //string orgExt = ((string)_text.Substring(_text.LastIndexOf(".") + 1, _text.Length - _text.LastIndexOf(".") - 1));
                    string orgExt = Path.GetExtension(context.Request.Files[0].FileName).ToLower();
                    orgExt = orgExt.Trim(char.Parse("."));
                    try
                    {
                        m.getProperty("umbracoExtension").Value = orgExt;
                    }
                    catch { }

                    // Save file size
                    try
                    {
                        System.IO.FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(_fullFilePath);
                        m.getProperty("umbracoBytes").Value = fi.Length.ToString();
                    }
                    catch { }

                    // Check if image and then get sizes, make thumb and update database
                    if (",jpeg,jpg,gif,bmp,png,tiff,tif,".IndexOf("," + orgExt + ",") > 0)
                    {
                        int fileWidth;
                        int fileHeight;

                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(_fullFilePath,
                            FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

                        System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
                        fileWidth = image.Width;
                        fileHeight = image.Height;
                        fs.Close();
                        try
                        {
                            m.getProperty("umbracoWidth").Value = fileWidth.ToString();
                            m.getProperty("umbracoHeight").Value = fileHeight.ToString();
                        }
                        catch { }

                        // Generate thumbnails
                        string fileNameThumb = _fullFilePath.Replace("." + orgExt, "_thumb");
                        generateThumbnail(image, 100, fileWidth, fileHeight, _fullFilePath, orgExt, fileNameThumb + ".jpg");

                        image.Dispose();
                    }
                    mediaPath = "/media/" + m.Id.ToString() + "/" + filename;

                    m.getProperty("umbracoFile").Value = mediaPath;
                    m.XmlGenerate(new XmlDocument());

                    Member mbr = Member.GetCurrentMember();
                    umbraco.cms.businesslogic.property.Property avt = mbr.getProperty("memberAvatar");
                    avt.Value = m.Id;
                    mbr.XmlGenerate(new XmlDocument());
                    mbr.Save();
                    //string commerceFileName = mediaPath;
                    //CommerceSave(commerceFileName);
                }
            }
            return mediaPath;
        }

        protected void generateThumbnail(System.Drawing.Image image, int maxWidthHeight, int fileWidth, int fileHeight, string fullFilePath, string ext, string thumbnailFileName)
        {
            // Generate thumbnail
            float fx = (float)fileWidth / (float)maxWidthHeight;
            float fy = (float)fileHeight / (float)maxWidthHeight;
            // must fit in thumbnail size
            float f = Math.Max(fx, fy); //if (f < 1) f = 1;
            int widthTh = (int)Math.Round((float)fileWidth / f); int heightTh = (int)Math.Round((float)fileHeight / f);

            // fixes for empty width or height
            if (widthTh == 0)
                widthTh = 1;
            if (heightTh == 0)
                heightTh = 1;

            // Create new image with best quality settings
            Bitmap bp = new Bitmap(widthTh, heightTh);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bp);
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            g.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

            // Copy the old image to the new and resized
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, widthTh, heightTh);
            g.DrawImage(image, rect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            // Copy metadata
            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
            ImageCodecInfo codec = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
            {
                if (codecs[i].MimeType.Equals("image/jpeg"))
                    codec = codecs[i];
            }

            // Set compresion ratio to 90%
            EncoderParameters ep = new EncoderParameters();
            ep.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 90L);

            // Save the new image
            bp.Save(thumbnailFileName, codec, ep);
            bp.Dispose();
            g.Dispose();

        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I hope this shed some light on what i use.

Comment: Thanks heaps for this Sander... I would love to change over to a simpler, more elegant jQuery solution, however there is no money in this for me, and its not just a straight swap-over, because:

1. My form needs to allow users to upload between 1 and 3 images
2. It must show a progress bar (images might be large)

If you think it'll be easy to extend this example to meet my needs, i'll certainly look into it further... but i was hoping to just find the problem with my current solution and fix it.

Cheers
Greg

Answer (score 0):

Pfew,..That's a lot of code.

I was only interessted in saving media in Umbraco but it's nice to see a jQuery upload too.

What upload jQuery lib your using? I've found serveral.

You could make the code a bit simpler by using Path.Combine, FileInfo.Extension merging if's and a few extra variables here an there. But hey I've got Resharper to make my live easier.